# Select the text from a CSS selector using jQuery (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Running this in the console:

```
$('#background-experience h4 a')
```

Returns a list of:

```
<a href='someURL.com' name='something' title='title class='class>SOME TEXT</a>
```

How do I select the first element from the list and then "SOME TEXT"?

```
$('#background-experience h4 a').text()
```

returns all of the "SOME TEXT". But

```
$('#background-experience h4 a')[0].text()
```

breaks with this error:

```
$('#background-experience h4 a')[0].text()
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "select".  Do you want the text as a string?  Are you interested in the [`Text` node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text)?

Comment: I am trying to get "SOME TEXT" from the first element in the list of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#background-experience h4 a').text();
```

To select the first element from the list and then "SOME TEXT-

```
$('#background-experience h4 a:eq(0)').text()
```

Comment: $('#background-experience h4 a') returns a list. When I try to select the first one from that list by [0] and then add .text() to it, I get an error. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MorganAllen Try $('#background-experience h4 a:eq(0)').text();

Comment: @MorganAllen It reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index (in your case it will be first child since index is 0 i.e. eq(0)).

Comment: @MorganAllen Could you accept the answer if your are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

Use the .text() method like this:

$('#background-experience h4 a').text();

Pure JS solution:

Use innerHTML() like:

document.getElementsByName('something')[0].innerHTML;

This is just a selector sample. There are multiple ways to select an element.

If you want to select the first occurance of an element you can use the css selector :first-child or the method .eq(0) after the jquery selector